# Open Trip Planner returns 0 itinerary

Tags: java, openstreetmap, gtfs, opentripplanner

I'm using Open Trip Planner with GTFS data that is already provided. I got them from https://transitfeeds.com/feeds, and I'm encountering an issue where it doesn't return any itinerary. The data seems to be loaded correctly, but the planner isn't generating itinerary.

What I did was creating otp file that contains the shaded and the gtfs zip file then I run it from the command prompt using this command:

```
java -Xmx4G -jar otp-2.1.0-shaded.jar --build --serve C:\Users\Asus\otp
```

then it works, but when I choose start and end destinations I can't find any route even by walking.

Has anyone experienced a similar issue, and if so, what steps did you take to troubleshoot and resolve it? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!